# Tools for Monitoring Web Services, Windows Services, App Pools and MSMQ health

Tags: web-services, windows-services, msmq

I am tasked with rewriting a series of legacy services (win and web + msmq). Because of the state they are in, I cannot quickly add functionality to them so they 'call home' to report status/health. I need to do the following:

- Poll win service for status: if not 'running', take action
- Monitor win service cpu usage: if above X for Y period, take action
- Monitor a MSMQ for # of messages: if above X, take action
- Monitor a table: if most recent record is older than X take action
- Monitor a web service mem and CPU usage: if above x, take action
- Open web page: if  not found, take action

The potential actions to take are:

- Start or Restart win service
- Recycle app pool
- Send Email
- Write record to history table in database

I know I can eventually accomplish all this by writing custom libraries that can be used by wcf or other services, but I wanted to investigate off the shelf products or tools that could do all or some of this.

What tools are available to do some or all of these tasks?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

At a simple level, Performance Monitor can perform tasks when MSMQ queue levels reach a set level. There are also MSMQ Management Packs for SCOM.

Comment: scom is cost prohibitive at this point, if I understand the licensing correctly ( > $1000 per machine you monitor)